# How to make special nohilight case in irssi

Tags: irssi

I would like to know how to set a special case to irssi hilight. I now have my nick in hilights and I would like to set it not to hilight when certain user writes it or it is written with certain characters.

For example: I am in a channel with a bot that prints out messages from a service and adds the person who said it to the start of the message. So my problem is that every time I talk in the service I get an unnecessary hilight from the bot in the channel with the message that I just said.

I don't want to ignore the bot, since it informs me if someone else is talking about me/for me in the service.

I noticed that there is NOHILIGHT in levels, but I don't know how to use it to achieve my goal here.

The bot says the user in form of < nick >, so best solution would be not get hilighted from the text "nick" if it is with certain other characters (in example < and > marks) and said by certain user (in example the bot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a <kbd>script</kbd> to do it for me made by cho45:
[nohilight.pl](https://github.com/cho45/dotfiles/blob/master/.irssi/scripts/autorun/nohilight.pl)